# NodeJS error while exporting a function to app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I have this function in app.js

```
    const LOLTrackingSystem = setInterval(async () => {
    await LOLUserData.LOLUserData(3, async (result) => { // [Step (2)]
      await summonerStats.summonerStats (result , async (result) => { // [Step (3)]
        await addPointsToUser.addPointsToUser(result) // [Step (4)] Final
      })
    })
  }, 2000);
```

working fine but I want to put the function in separate file and export it and use it in app.js here is what I have done

LOLTracking.js

```
    //=============================================================================
// LOL Ranked Games Wins Tracking System
//=============================================================================
const LOLUserData = require('../leagueOfLegends/getUserData')
const summonerStats = require('../leagueOfLegends/getSummonerStats')
const addPointsToUser = require('../gizmo/addPoints')

const LOLTrackingSystem = setInterval(async () => {
    await LOLUserData.LOLUserData(3, async (result) => { // [Step (2)]
      await summonerStats.summonerStats (result , async (result) => { // [Step (3)]
        await addPointsToUser.addPointsToUser(result) // [Step (4)] Final
      })
    })
  }, 2000);
exports.LOLTrackingSystem = LOLTrackingSystem
```

but now when i require it and use it in my app.js like this

```
 const LOLTrackingSystem = require('./src/methods/onlineGamesTracking/LOLTracking')

const run = async () => {

await LOLTrackingSystem.LOLTrackingSystem()

}

run()
```

I get an error saying

> TypeError: LOLTrackingSystem.LOLTrackingSystem is not a function

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, you have set the `LOLTrackingSystem` with an interval, which return an id and not a function it’s a misunderstanding.

So when you call it in your app it’s not a function.

What you can do is

```
LOLTrackingSystem = () => setInterval(..., 2000)
exports.LOLTrackingSystem = LOLTrackingSystem
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much :)